# common practice for member and parameter storage

Tags: c++

seeking general guidance on common design practice here in > c++14 world.

Is `const std::string& mName` the most appropriate type here? it has the least copies, but is it good style?

I feel like a ref implies some other alias that is or could be in unknown state at some point.

Is it best style for one to make the defensive copy? and go `const std::string mName` instead? or if that is the case take the copy in the parameter `const std::string aName` and keep the & in the member field?

whats the most common practice for parameter and member storage and what are the factors that push the decision in other ways?

```
class Machine {
private:
    const std::string& mName;

public:
    Machine(const std::string& aName) : mName(aName) {
        std::cout << &aName << std::endl;
        std::cout << &mName << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::string x = "Number 1";
    std::cout << &x << std::endl;
    Machine m(x);
    Machine m2("Number 6");
}
```

- EDIT *

This feels better and also eliminate extra copy on temporaries I think??

```
class Machine {
private:
    const std::string mName;

public:
    Machine(const std::string&& aName) : mName(aName) {
        std::cout << "1:: " << &aName << std::endl;
        std::cout << "1:: " << &mName << std::endl;
    }

    Machine(const std::string& aName) : mName(aName) {
        std::cout << "2:: " << &aName << std::endl;
        std::cout << "2:: " << &mName << std::endl;
    }

    const std::string& name() const {
        return mName;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::string x = "Number 1";
    std::cout << &x << std::endl;
    Machine m(x);
    Machine m2("Number 6");
}
```

Comment: I can say that a reference member is a big red flag. Doesn't mean it's always a bad idea, but things can go wrong more easily.

Comment: The "best style" IMO is to choose what best models the problem. Don't choose based on some notion of "defensive" strategy. Should the object logically keep its own copy? Or should it reference someone else's copy? That can be quite a logical difference and I don't feel they are particularly interchangeable.

Comment: What happens if a `Machine` outlives the string it references? That's frustrating for callers to pay attention to for the sake of a copy

Comment: I agree, feels wrong.

Comment: Yes Galik, but in the general case I mean

Comment: The question is one of ownership and lifetimes.   If you're going to store a pointer (or reference..) in a class, you have to ask yourself who owns that and what is their lifetime?  As an aside, putting references in classes causes all sorts of headaches with things like default copy/move constructors and whatnot, whereas with a pointer, it is always a shallow copy.  So if you are going to store a pointer/reference that should never be null, I recommend taking it as a reference parameter, but then storing it as a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to store the constructor parameter in your object, then take the object by value.   If the caller passes an rvalue, it will be move constructed in.   If the user passes an lvalue, you were going to have to create a copy when you copy it into your object, anyhow, so just do it a step earlier.

This results in the cleanest, easiest to understand code:

```
class Machine {
private:
    const std::string mName;

public:
    Machine(const std::string aName) : mName(std::move(aName)) {
        std::cout << "1:: " << &aName << std::endl; // this has been moved out of...
        std::cout << "1:: " << &mName << std::endl;
    }


    const std::string& name() const {
        return mName;
    }
};

int main() {
    Machine m(function_that_returns_a_string()); // move constructed all the way in - no copies made
    string s;
    Machine m2(s); // only one copy is made - when calling constructor, but it's then move constructed into the object
}
```

There are times when objects are still too expensive to move construct, at which point making two versions taking an rvalue and lvalue reference will be a win, but for most cases, the style above is the best approach.

Comment: @Jarod42 ahh yes ok i can reason why that would be the case. thanks. whats a good way to instrument move taking place in this instance for clarity of demonstration? my initial thought of printing the address doesnt really work i suppose as the internals are transferred from one memory location shell to another, not kept and pushed over to the new handle holder from param to member